# Handle subdomain on nginx running on Docker based ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a scenario composed by a frontend and backend Docker containers and another container for the nginx reverse proxy.

Currently, the nginx configuration points the url http://example.com to frontend container and http://example.com/backend to the backend container.

Now I need to configure nginx so it can also understand calls to http://backend.example.com and redirect them to the backend container.

How can I achieve that if the server name that is used on nginx config is localhost?

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    }

    location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass   http://backend:3000/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://frontend:3000/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I tried adding this block too, but it didn't work (in fact it made everything stop working):

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  backend.localhost;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://backend:3000/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try server_name backend.example.com

Comment: Didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

I create test env. Add xyz.com and backend.xyz.com to my "hosts" file.
This works for me

```html
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xyz.com;

    location /backend/ {
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8081/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://frontend:8082/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  backend.xyz.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8081/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```